# Meteor and Iron Router subscription queries

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I found that I can just call a findOne in a global function and I'll have access to the subscription...  The only thing I'm confused about is, how global a function distinguishes between collections, one subscription to the other.

// pubs

```
Meteor.publish("just_dob_and_id_shared_collection", function () {
  return shared_collection.find({_id: this.userId}, {fields: {'dob': 1}});
});

Meteor.publish("entire_recordset_shared_collection", function () {
  return shared_collection.find({_id: this.userId});
});
```

// IR controllers

```
fooController = RouteController.extend({
  template: 'foo-template',
  waitOn: function () {
    Meteor.subscribe("just_dob_and_id_shared_collection");
  },
...
});

barController = RouteController.extend({   
  template: 'bar-template',   
  waitOn: function () {
    Meteor.subscribe("entire_recordset_shared_collection");   }, 
... 
});
```

// global functions

```
fooFunction = function () {
  var foo = shared_collection.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId()});
  // in this case I'll have the _id and dob... this is kinda what I've tested
  // ## will be used in foo-template
}

barFunction = function () {
  var bar = shared_collection.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId()});
  // in this case maybe I'd want the entire record set to do stuff with
  // ## will be used in bar-template
}
```

// template helpers

```
Template.registerHelper("fooHelper", function () {
  fooFunction();
}

Template.registerHelper("barHelper", function () {
  barFunction();
}
```

// templates

```
<template name="foo-template">
  {{#if fooHelper}}
  ...
  {{/if}}
<template>

<template name="bar-template">
  {{#if barHelper}}
  ...
  {{/if}}
<template>
```

### EDIT: To clarify further

I have two subscriptions, each pulling (maybe from the same record-set) different data profiles (portions of a record-set from a document within a collection).

On the client, when I do a findOne on the collection name (since I don't do it on the subscription name),

> (1) which/what record-set (data profile) do I get when I call, for example the fooFunction, and why?,
>
> (2) when does this data profile change, for example when I go to the bar-template and its subscription is called (in this case it gets all fields in the record-set, not just dob and the _id), does the recordset change when I call findOne in the fooFunction?  I ask this because I'm doing a findOne on the collection, not subscription name, so in the fooFunction, theres no distinction between subscriptions. So maybe asked another way -- does the timing of the call in the fooFunction, to the collection, change the result of the findOne?

Comment: Your publications simply allow your client access to a **subset** of your server's `shared_collection`. When you are on the client and you do `shared_collection.find().fetch()` you will be fetching the subset of `shared_collection` that was published to the client. The `shared_collection` on the client simply contains the documents you chose to publish to it.

Comment: I edited the question on account of your comment.